# Convert string of array of objects to JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to parse an array of objects as JSON Objects. However, after running my code and getting the first element I get `[`. How can I parse an array as a string to an array of JSON objects?

```
let t = `["{"name": "a", "description": "b", "imageType": "c"}", "{"name": "aa", "description": "bb", "imageType": "cc"}"]`;
let tString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t));
console.log(tString[0])
let tArray = tString.map(x => JSON.parse(x))
```

Currently I want `tString[0]` to print `{"name": "a", "description": "b", "imageType": "c"}`

Comment: First, try to make a [example]. What you put in the code is probably not what the input is actually (should the double quotes be escaped? Etc. In the current form it's next to impossible to parse the data correctly

Comment: Your string is not a valid JSON. It has `"{ ... }"` and should be `{ ... }` without quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is a string (of invalid JSON).

`JSON.stringify(t)` converts it to a string of JSON representing the original string.

`JSON.parse` then parses that JSON giving `tString` a value identical to the original `t`.

(Which makes that whole bit of conversion entirely pointless).

`tString[0]` then accesses the first character (because it is a string) of that.

---

If you want to use JSON then make `t` **valid** JSON in the first place. Then parse it. Then access the result. Don't do anything else.

There doesn't seen to be any point in using JSON here though. You should just make `t` an array literal containing object literals.